# Mongoose default field-value in schema seems not to work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

An error occurs when createPost function is called.

The error message is: 
'E11000 duplicate key error collection: photogram-db.posts index: likes_1 dup key: { likes: undefined }'

The error occurs because of duplicate value of likes field but the likes field is not set be unique ({ unique: true }) and secondly why is likes undefined it should be defaulted to an empty array and lastly the only value supposed to be unique is Account Object referens inside the field likes.

The error is thrown exactly when the post.save() method is called inside the createPost function

```
import {
    Schema,
    model,
    Document
}
from "mongoose";

import { 
    AccountModel,
    IAccountDocument, 
    IAccount
} 
from "./account";

import { 
    createNotification 
} 
from "./notification";

import removeItemInArray, { checkIdFn } from "../utilities/removeItemInArray";

import hasItemInArray from "../utilities/hasItemInArray";
import settings from "../settings";
import { searchModel } from "./searchHelper";



export interface IPost {
    title: String;

    image: Buffer;

    text?: String;
}

export interface IPostInit extends IPost {
    creator: IAccountDocument["_id"]
}

export interface IPostDocument extends IPostInit, Document {
    likes: Array<IAccountDocument["_id"]>;

    dislikes: Array<IAccountDocument["_id"]>;

    createdAt: Date;
};



const {
    Types: {
        String,
        Buffer,
        ObjectId
    }
} = Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,

        required: true
    },

    text: {
        type: String,

        require: false
    },

    image: {
        type: Buffer,

        require: true
    },



    createdAt: {
        type: Date,

        default: new Date(),

        required: false
    },

    creator: {
        type: ObjectId,

        ref: "Account",

        required: true
    },



    likes: {
        type: [{
            type: ObjectId,

            ref: "Account",

            required: false,

            unique: true
        }],

        default: [],

        required: false
    },

    disLikes: {
        type: [{
            type: ObjectId,

            ref: "Account",

            required: false,

            unique: true
        }],

        default: [],

        required: false
    }
});

PostSchema.index({
    title: "text",
    text: "text"
});

export const createPost = async (settings: IPostInit) => {

    const post = new PostModel(settings);

    post.createdAt = new Date();

    await post.save();

    return post;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made i silly mistake. Unique field can only be used on document properties and not on item in array inside a document property.